# How can I run a Selenium Python Script in the Cloud?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python script that uses Chromedriver and selenium to scrape a handful of websites. What resources are currently used to run these type of python scripts in the cloud?

For reference, I am using `version 84.0.4147.30`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to setup an EC2 instance and install chrome, chromedriver and python...